# Unable to get inventory status of configurable products

Tags: cart, configurable-product, inventory, simple-product

I am having some trouble and perhaps a few people here can expand my knowledge.  Here is the code I am using to retrieve some information about a product on my cart page.

```
    if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
        $sku = $_item->getSku();
        var_dump($sku);
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
        $invStatus = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        var_dump($invStatus);
        $quantity = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
        var_dump($quantity);
```

If the product is found to be configurable I retrieve the sku of the simple product it is associated with and then set the product to that configured simple product.  I then get the inentory status and the quantity of that product.  And this is where the issue arises.  This is the result of that vardump:

```
string(6) "421199" string(2) "No" string(6) "1.0000"
```

When a similar methodology is enacted upon simple products I receive the following from the following code:

```
        var_dump($product->getSku());
        $invStatus = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        var_dump($invStatus);
        $quantity = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
        var_dump($quantity);
```

.

```
string(4) "DWCP" string(1) "Z" string(6) "0.0000"
```

The inventory status is definitely also set from the admin panel.  Any suggestions or incites would be appreciated.

--

Also, if I add the simple product as the item itself (from another part of the site) then the string resolves to the correct value.  It's when I'm fetching the product in this manner that non-resolvency becomes apparent.

Why doesn't magento handle products uniformly?? It makes NO sense at all.

Comment: edited with additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue I was running into was that `loadByAttribute()` does not act in the same way that `load()` does and therefore I would need to fetch the id of the simple product then once again load the simple product. Below is the corrected code:

```
$productId = $_item->getProductId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
if($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
    $sku = $_item->getSku();
    $simpProdId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku)->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simpProdId);
}
$invStatus = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
$quantity = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem, you need to change :

```
    $sku = $_item->getSku();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
    $invStatus = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
    var_dump($invStatus);
    $quantity = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
    var_dump($quantity);
```

by

```
    $invStatus = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('product_inventory_status')->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
    var_dump($invStatus);
    $quantity = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_item)->getQty();
    var_dump($quantity);
```

Normaly, $_item is an instance of mage_catalog_model_product. Therefore, you can use the method of that class. You should have access to all the attributes of you product if their visibility is set accordingly to the place where you call the product.

Comment: When I inserted your alteration for $invStatus into my code the page stops rendering at $invStatus (the vardump of $sku completes but not for $invstatus) so something is incorrect.. but the purpose of getting the items sku and creating a new product from that is because the $items sku is that which is associated with the configurable products realized simple product, right?